# Try to stop external loaded Youtube swf

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube

I've use AS3 Youtube API to load youtube video into my flash file, let's call it youtube.swf

I've a main.swf and it loaded youtube.swf into it's stage.
I try to unload this youtube.swf and load in another new.swf, but the sound of youtube still running.

I've insert the player.destroy() in the main.swf but it's not working too.

Any idea that I can destroy the youtube video with the script in main.swf?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the loaded SWF - the one with the YouTube player inside, you can create a public API methods for playing, stopping, etc. that can later be called by SWFs that are using it.

To create a public API it's only needed to create public methods inside the document class or if you're using frame scripts - creating public functions in the first frame. In those methods you could delegate calls to the YouTube API. Then the main SWF, before removing the loaded one, should call the "stop()" or similar method on the loaded content and then for example remove it from the display list.

Answer (score 0):

try to have your swf on a https resoure. its possible that your YT API functions will be back working then.